# Gimp: How to batch resize ONE image in multiple sizes and export them?

Tags: plugins, batch-processing, gimp

Is there any way to resize an image (jpg/ jpeg)on a range of predefined sizes and export at once on Gimp? (same image-different sizes batch scale and batch export).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

From the Gimp GUI, there is a script/plug-in for this, see `ofn-export-sizes` [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/)(*).

If you want to do that in batch, it is a lot easier/faster to use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/), which is designed to be used from a shell script:

```
magick convert input.jpg -resize 500x output-500px.jpg
```

(here `500x` means resize to 500px wide and keep aspect ratio, you can otherwise set
height, width or both). You can even apply a bit of sharpening to compensate for the blur:

```
magick convert input.jpg -resize 500x -sharpen 0x1.0 output-500px.jpg
```

For more info, there is a rather active [stream of ImageMagick questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagemagick) here on SO.

(*) Note that in Gimp, a script usable in batch doesn't need to be a plugin, this is required only if you want to use the script from the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in Imagemagick command line. For Imagemagick 6 on Unix:

```
convert image.jpg -write mpr:img +delete \
\( mpr:img -resize W1xH1 +write result1.jpg \) \
\( mpr:img -resize W2xH2 +write result2.jpg \) \
\( mpr:img -resize W3xH3 +write result3.jpg \) \
...
null:
```

If on Windows

```
convert image.jpg -write mpr:img +delete ^
( mpr:img -resize W1xH1 +write result1.jpg ) ^
( mpr:img -resize W2xH2 +write result2.jpg ) ^
( mpr:img -resize W3xH3 +write result3.jpg ) ^
...
null:
```

If on Imagemagick 7, change `convert` to `magick`